# Analytics for shiny apps on GitHub

Tags: r, github, shiny

Is it possible to gather any sort of usage analytics for an R shiny app whose source code is on GitHub but that is only run locally? For instance, one of the following:

- Number of times the code is downloaded and executed with `shiny::runGitHub()`
- Number of times the app is run in the client computer

One can track the traffic to a GitHub repository with the [Insights tool](https://help.github.com/en/github/visualizing-repository-data-with-graphs/viewing-traffic-to-a-repository), but that does inform on whether the app is being used or not.

[Google Analytics](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/google-analytics.html) can be integrated into a shiny app, but that requires the app to be hosted at shinyapps.io or any other shiny server, which is not my situation at the moment.

Comment: It would suprise me if this existed. I've been trying to find a way to get stats about how often a package is downloaded from GitHub and that does not seem possible either.

Answer (score 0):

> Google Analytics can be integrated into a shiny app

Integrating analytics (Google or otherwise) into your application seems to be the only reliable option here, considering the nature of the Git repositories hosting service offered by GitHub.

Once a release artifact is downloaded... GitHub has no native way to know what/when/where it is executed.